# Dropzone.js doesn't upload .zip files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropzone.js

I have to upload ZIP archives with dropzone, when I select the archive I see the progress bar going from 0 to 100, but the request never reaches the server, the action I specified in my form is never called.
This is the file uploader on my page:

```
<form action="URL_ACTION" class="dropzone dropzone-file-area" id="dropzoneZip" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file" type="file" />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my JS code:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneZip = {
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drag files here o click to upload",
        maxFiles: 1,
        acceptedFiles: ".zip",
        init: function () {
            this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage) {
                alert("error : " + errorMessage);
            });
            this.on("addedfile", function (e) {
                var n = Dropzone.createElement("<a href='javascript:;' class='btn red btn-sm btn-block'>Remove</a>"),
                    t = this;
                n.addEventListener("click", function (n) {
                    n.preventDefault(), n.stopPropagation(), t.removeFile(e)
                }), e.previewElement.appendChild(n)
            }),
            this.on("complete", function (data) {
                if (data.xhr.responseText == "success") {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'File uploaded',
                        type: "success"
                    }).then(
                    function () {
                        $(".se-pre-con").fadeIn("slow");
                        location.reload();
                    })
                }
            }),
            this.on('error', function (file, errorMessage) {
                if (errorMessage != "success") {
                    var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
                    errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = errorMessage;
                }
                else if (errorMessage.indexOf('404') !== -1) {
                    var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
                    errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 404: The upload page was not found on the server';
                } else if (errorMessage.indexOf('500') !== -1) {
                    var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
                    errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 500: Internal server error';
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the code of my action where I check the file type:

```
  if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
  {
      if (Request["type"]=="zip" && (Request.Files[0].ContentType == "application/x-compressed" || Request.Files[0].ContentType == "application/x-zip-compressed" || Request.Files[0].ContentType == "application/zip" || Request.Files[0].ContentType == "multipart/x-zip"))
        uploadZip();
  }
```

But this action is never reached. I tried to upload images with the same method and it works normally. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

index.html

```
<html>

<head>   
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- 1 -->
<link href="dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- 2 -->
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .dropzone .dz-preview {
        display:none;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>


<form  action="upload.php" class="dropzone dropzone-file-area" id="dropzoneZip" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file" type="file" />

  </div>
</form><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="submit-all" />

<script>

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.

    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.

    });

  }
};
</script></body></html>
```

update.php

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

if you have xamp/uniserver then its fully working I have tested the above code
Create an uploads folder for the place to upload the files in the server

Comment: Sorry, I had to specify that I'm using ASP.NET,. If you have ideas I'm open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out why: the file that I tried to upload exceeded the maxRequestLength parameter on the Web.config file. With smaller files the upload works correctly